# how to dynamic create process using python

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

Is there a way to dynamically generate processes to handle the same batch of data.

Let say i use three different account to chat with the same robot, i could not figure out any convenient approach, so i just create process manually

```
def chat(bot, query_list):
        for idx, query in enumerate(query_list):
            answer = bot.chat(query)
            print(answer)

#Let say there is a function called bot, parameter is account information
robot1 = bot(account1)
robot2 = bot(account2)
robot3 = bot(account3)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=chat, args=(robot1, data[0],))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=chat, args=(robot2, data[1],))
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=chat, args=(robot3, data[2],))


p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
print('Done!')
```

But this way is kind of stiff， cause i have to manually create tons of processes if i have tons of account. So is there any function or pythonic way to achieve the same purpose ?

Comment: Use a loop? Isn't there a `map` analog for multiprocessing?

Comment: @wwii  I used to think about using a pool but I don't know how to use it

Comment: There are examples in the documentation that you could probably adapt to your situation - you should try it.

Comment: What does `bot.chat` represent in your program? What is involved in running that function?

Comment: @duskwuff `bot.chat` just get the query as input and output answer. I just imagine that.

Comment: @PeterTsung Input from what? The terminal? An online API? Something else?

Comment: @duskwuff just pass it to the function, sorry i may not get your point/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a process pool to create a dynamic number of processes, and represent your tasks as properly separated jobs to distribute work:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# each entry of `job_list` contains all the information
# required to perform a single task.
job_list = [
    {
        "account": {
            "username": "john",
            "password": "qwerty"
        },
        "query": "How can I help you?"
    } # , ...
]

# function executed for each element of `job_list`
def run_job(job):
    print("account user name: {}".format(job["account"]["username"]))
    print("query: {}".format(job["query"]))
    # answer query here using account

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    pool.map(run_job, job_list)
```